# Updating Subscriber Status from Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm looking to update unsubscribes (there's a list of 500 emails on a csv file that I've been given) in the Marketing Cloud system, however I can only import them as Data Extensions as they do not come with a Subscriber Key. The Marketing Cloud system already has subscriber keys for each email address.

Comment: What do you mean by updating unsubscribes? Do you want to change the status?

Comment: Is the susbscribr key in marketing cloud the email or something else?

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload this list of email addresses as a data extension
2. Using a Target Data Extension containing EmailAddress, SubscriberKey and Status (in the same formats as those columns in the Subscriber table, and assuming all other fields in Susbcribers are nullable), write a query to get the subscribers from the All Subscribers list, with a join on email address or using a 'Where Exists' clause, for example

`SELECT * FROM _Subscribers WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DataExtension WHERE _Subscribers.EmailAddress = DataExtension.EmailAddress)`

3. This should give you everyone from the Subscribers Data View who matches on your uploaded Data Extension on the email address, and will now also give you the Subscriber Key for these people, as well as their status.
4. Export this newly populated data extension
5. Open it up in Excel, change all the Status values to **Unsubscribe** or whatever you want to do with them.
6. Go to All Subscribers, click Import, choose Update Only. Map the fields like you do with a normal import and it will update all these subscribers with the new status.